# ajax controlling in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hey guys I need to know the answers to some questions. **First** of all how do I handle ajax call when I am not returning anything from the controller because it always ask me for the view for the called function but since I have called that function using ajax how can it have a view.(I am using it in ROR(ruby on rails))

bookmark.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
      <div id="page-wrapper-lbms" class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns dashboard-page">

        <input type="hidden" id="bookmarked_against_req_id" value=<%= @data2%> />
        <%
        if @requests != nil
         @requests.each.with_index do |request,index| 

          if request != nil
          %>
      <header>
        <div style="text-align:center">
          <a href="#" onclick="ajax_bookmark('<%= request.id %>' , '<%=@request_id%>')" ><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span></a>
        </div> 
        <h2 style="text-align:center"><%= request.title  %></h2>

        <div style="text-align:center">
          <h6 style="color:#aaaaaa"><strong><%= request.is_service%></strong></h6>
        </div>
      </header>
        <div class ="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-8 columns">  

        <div id="request-content-lbms" class="panel">
          <p>
            <%= request.description%>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="list-request-cat-lbms">
          <span class="fa fa-tag"></span>
          <% if @tag[index] != nil
              @tag[index].each do |cat| %>
                 <%= cat.title %> 
             <%end%>
          <%end%>
        </div>
      </div>
      <aside class="small-12 medium-12 large-4 columns" style="padding-left:10%"> 

          <h3 ><strong>Syed Muhammad Ali Gardezi</strong></h3>
          <time><%= request.created_at %></time><br />
          <%end%>
          <button class="button tiny">Schedule Meeting</button>
      </aside>
    </div>
   </div>

  <%end%>
  <%end%>




  <script>
    function ajax_bookmark(abc , cde){

      var cde = $('#bookmarked_against_req_id').val();
      $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'bookmark_request',
    data: {
      d:abc,
      d1:cde
    },
        error:function(){

    },
    dataType: 'json',
    //beforeSend:function(){},
    //complete:function(o,s){},
    success:function(data){
      location.href ="/requests/bookmark"
    },
    type: 'get'
  });
    }
  </script
```

bookmark_request

```
def bookmark_request()

    data = params[:d]
    data1 = params[:d1]
    data2 = data1#["$oid"]#.split('"' , 6)
    #asd
    request_bookmarked = Request.getRequest(data)
    bookmarked_against_Request = Request.getRequest(data2)
    request_bookmarked_2 = request_bookmarked
    bookmarked_against_Request_2 = bookmarked_against_Request
    #asd
    if bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites]
      bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << request_bookmarked[:id]
    else

      bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] = Array.new
      bookmarked_against_Request[:favourites] = Array.new
      bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << request_bookmarked[:id]
    end  

    if request_bookmarked_2[:favourites_of]
      request_bookmarked_2[:favourites_of] << bookmarked_against_Request[:id]

    else
      request_bookmarked_2[:favourites_of] = Array.new
      request_bookmarked[:favourites_of] = Array.new
      request_bookmarked_2[:favourites_of] << bookmarked_against_Request[:id]
    end  

    request_bookmarked.update(Hash['favourites' ,request_bookmarked_2[:favourites]])
    bookmarked_against_Request.update(Hash['favourites' ,bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites]])
    #asd

    bookmarks = Bookmark.where(request_id: bookmarked_against_Request[:id]).first()
    #asd
    b = bookmarks
  if bookmarks != nil
    #bookmarks.each { |bookmark| bookmark.update_attributes(corsponding_requests: request_bookmarked[:id]) }
    b[:corsponding_requests] << request_bookmarked[:id]
    b.update(Hash['corsponding_requests' , b[:corsponding_requests]] )    

  else

    bookmark = Hash.new
    bookmark["owner_req"] = session[:user]
    bookmark["request_id"] = bookmarked_against_Request[:id]
    bookmark["corsponding_requests"] = Array.new
    bookmark["corsponding_requests"] <<  request_bookmarked[:_id]
    Bookmark.createBookmark(bookmark)

  end

  flash[:notice] = "Request has been bookmarked successfully."
end
```

Now when ever I run this function i need it to go into the success function of ajax in bookmark.html.erb but the problem is it says I can't find the view. What is it that I am doinf wrong over here

**Second** when ever I need to return something I have read that I need to make a html helper but I can't figure out what a html helper is. and how can I return a string back to ajax function

Any help will be appreciated (I am new to AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

Gonna try to answer you :

**First:**
If you have a special action for your ajax call you only need:

```
def custom_action
end
```

This will render the `custom_action.js.erb` if called with ajax, for example a form with `remote: true`.

If you call one of your CRUD-actions and need to be able to respond to multiple formats:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id]) 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # will render show.html.erb
    format.js # will render show.js.erb
  end
end
```

If you put a link in your view:

```
link_to('Remote Ajax Call', book_path(@book), remote: true)
```

This link will call the method show and render as `:js`.
It will look for `app/views/books/show.js.erb` which may look something like:

```
<% if @book.present? %>
  $('#book-title').html("<%=@book.title%>");
<%end%>
```

And in your view, close to the link above, this will then change the text inside a html-tag with I'd `book-title`.

```
<div id="book-title"> 
</div>
```

**Second:**

I do not understand what you mean by

> ...need to return something...

Can you add an example?

Hope that this can help you a bit.

**Edit**:
This is my try to understand what you want to do:
In your view:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :bookmarked_against_req_id, value: @data2 %> 
  <% if @requests != nil %>
    <% @requests.each.with_index do |request,index| %> 
      <% if request.present? %>
        <%= link_to 'Bookmark it', bookmark_request_path(request), remote: true %>
        <%= request.title  %>
        <%= request.is_service%>
        <%= request.description%>
        <% if @tag[index].present? %>
          <% @tag[index].each do |cat| %>
            <%= cat.title %> 
          <%end%>
        <%end%>
        <%= request.created_at %>
       <%end%> 
  <%end%>
 <%end%>
```

In your controller:

```
def bookmark_request()
  request_bookmarked = Request.getRequest(params[:id]) # the params[:id] should be set in the request.
  bookmarked_agains_Request = Request.getRequest(params[:bookmarked_against_req_id) # This is defined in your hidden_field_tag
```

When your action `bookmark_request`is done. If the request was AJAX you will render the JavaScript-file `bookmark_request.js.erb`

Here you should have the script you put in your view:

If the resource is saved, you should put JavaScript to render 'Success' or if it failed you should do otherwise.

The `flash[:notice] = "Request has been bookmarked successfully."`will not be understood by your AJAX-request.

Comment: will this format.html take me to the success function of ajax. since I need to do something in there

and in the second like I need to return a string or a object back like 
"great" or a object say of Books

Comment: I added an example on how to use the ajax-response. If I understand correctly I think this is what you want in the second part as well.

Comment: the thing is I need the return value to be first returned in the ajax success function 

and the second thing is when ever I am not returning anything it starts giving me error that the application cannot find the view. I just need to return to ajax success function in this case to

Comment: If you are not doing anything in your action - why do you have to use ajax? It seems like a normal GET

Comment: well that's our professor's requirement so I need to do it

Comment: it's the requirement so I have to do it ands it's a crud operation. But the thing it's I do not want to render the page accordinf to my function name e.g if I have a bookmark_request method I would like to call bookmark.html.erb page

Comment: You can always add `render 'bookmark'` in your method to specify the file name.
But if you do an ajax request this will require the file 'bookmark.js.erb'.

Comment: why bookmark.js.erb ?

and there is no file named bookmark.js.erb

Comment: See my updated answer, you need to separate the html-view and your JavaScript-response when you do an AJAX-request. 
That is why this file is chosen, a .html cannot be the response to an AJAX, it wants a .js

Comment: There is one thing I want to know. let's say I put the ajax in a file called bookmark.js.erb (seaparting it from bookmark.html.erb in which all of the html is present for this page). Now I reder bookmark.js.erb and this call the success function then ?? and from that will I be able to bookmark.html.erb

and one other thing if I render partial view will it be ok from ajax point of view ?

Comment: In rails you do not have to do the AJAX-request yourself, if you put a link with `remote: true`, then rails works the AJAX-magic for you.


So what you put in the `bookmark.js.erb` is only your responses, success and error. Then you decide what JavaScript-action you want to do in both cases.

Comment: can you just give me this in normal html  form. Not using helpers. I just want to see how would I write remote:true in simple html 

`<%= link_to 'Bookmark it', bookmark_request_path(request), remote: true %>`

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to take a look at the rails guides - they're a great source of general grounding: http://guides.rubyonrails.org. For returning different responses based on the request format (ajax vs. html), see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data and @davidwessman's answer above.

Generally, you'll typically return JSON data from an ajax request; so, for instance, in the controller you might say

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render json: @my_ojects.to_json} 
end
```

Note that there are several ways to render json, including the gems like [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). If you're returning json like that, you don't need to render a rails view (unless you're using a view to build your json, like rabl does or is hinted at in davidwessman's answer with js.erb).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Matt there is still a problem how can I get in the success function of ajax since I need to do something in that format.html will take me to the view which corresponds to my function. I have a function let's say bookmark_request. I just updates some of the things and then it need to returns to the bookmark.html.erb

Comment: and I need to render a json from a function let's say b on a view let's say a.html.erb how can I do that since simple render json: --- will not take me back to the success function of ajax